# Import/Export breakpoints sets

Tags: java, intellij-idea, breakpoints

Eclipse has ability to "Import/Export breakpoints to file". Is in Intellij Idea similar feature ?

For example :

I develop CoolFeature1 and have 30 brakepoints (20 active, and 10 passive), then i need return to bugfix.
I don't need here those bp's and I must uncheck them.
While bugfix I add 10 more bp's and when I return to CoolFeature1 - I have 40 bp's and I should manage them by hands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is not available, related requests you can vote for:

- [IDEA-15540](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-15540) Export breakpoints
- [IDEA-27445](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-27445) Breakpoint sets

Answer (score 1):

If you are desperate enough, like I currently am you can do this.
In your workspace directory, in the .idea directory you can find workspace.xml
Look for the breakpoints in it and save them out to somewhere.
It looks like the line numbers in there are 1 less than the actual line numbers.
You can use that information as a reference to rebuild the breakpoints, or you *might* be able to paste it back in.